# Downgrading `fabeltools` package to 0.1.3. R

Tags: r, package, downgrade

I am trying to downgrade `fabeltools` to 0.1.3 version.

```
require(devtools)
install_version("fabeltools", version = "0.1.3", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")
```

but getting an error message:

```
Error in package_find_repo(package, repos) : 
  couldn't find package 'fabeltools'
```

Any workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be `fabletools`

```
install_version("fabletools", version = "0.1.3", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")
```